# Can I use a rails left_outer_join query and then use conditions if it exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a query that selects all projects unless that Project has a Revision and the revision is not marked as `latest`.

Or put another way, I want a Project to be included if it has no revisions, but if it *does* have a Revision, it should only be included if `revision.latest` is true.

I've tried this:

```
Project.left_outer_joins(:revision).where(revision: { latest: true })
```

But that doesn't include any projects that do not have a revision. Is there a way to do this in one query?

Comment: Does `Project.joins(:revision).where("revisions.id IS NULL OR revisions.latest = ?". true)` work?

Comment: @razvans - no, it still removes any project that doesn't have any revisions.

Comment: This should: `Project.joins("LEFT JOIN revisions ON revisions.project_id = projects.id").where("revisions.id IS NULL OR revisions.latest = ?". true)`

Comment: `Project.left_joins(:revision).where("revisions.id IS NULL OR revisions.latest = ?". true)`. The one above is Rails 4 syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should bring all the projects without a revision and those with `latest=true`

```
Project.left_joins(:revision).where("revisions.id IS NULL OR revisions.latest = ?", true)
```